# Is there any way to prevent a bad drive from disappearing from /dev?

Tags: partition, devices, udev, block-device, badblocks

I'm trying to recover a partition on a bad drive with ddrescue. I run:

```
$ sudo ddrescue -r -1 -v /dev/sdd3 OUT.img dd_rescue_logfile
```

and it seems to do great for a while, but after about an hour, the "current rate" drops to zero because the drive disappeared from /dev. To bring the drive back, the only thing I can think of is to reboot the system and run the ddrescue command to resume from where I left off. This makes it very difficult to run the program, as I can't just leave it and forget it for a few days - I have to constantly monitor it to make sure the disk didn't disappear. I have seen this behavior on both Arch linux, and Fedora 22.

I assume that at some point, the kernel has trouble accessing the drive and removes it from /dev. Is there any way to avoid this? To tell the kernel to keep the device there even if it looks like it's broken or non-existent?

Comment: I guess you have a hardware issue...

Comment: Duplicate of [ddrescue attempt ends with drive disappearing from /dev](https://superuser.com/q/768377/499711)

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to re-detect it without reboot, by unloading / re-loading the correct module (or just un-binding and re-binding the driver).

For example:

```
[  978.527221] sd 11:0:0:1: [sdk] Attached SCSI removable disk
#~> echo 11:0:0:1 > /sys/bus/scsi/drivers/sd/unbind
#~> echo 11:0:0:1 > /sys/bus/scsi/drivers/sd/bind
[ 5572.027119] sd 11:0:0:1: [sdk] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Or if that does not work and you have no other devices hooked to the same controller, you could unbind and bind the entire controller for example via `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/ahci/` if it's AHCI.

I don't have any defective HDD to test if it would actually work, but I used this method before to force re-detection of MicroSD/MMC cards in slots that were not hot-pluggable by default.

As for `ddrescue` dropping speed to zero, you might want to see if it supports the `-a, --min-read-rate=<bytes>` option so it would hopefully? consider slow regions as defective and skip them. Worst case you'll have to monitor the disk from the outside and forcibly restart `ddrescue`.

Comment: dmesg was showing me a ton of errors on 'sd 4:0:0:0', so I'm assuming that's the drive I'm looking for. I tried unbinding and binding it like you suggested, but it's still not visible. How do I check if it's the only drive on the controller, and which controllers I have available?

Comment: `lspci`, and if it's AHCI, `ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ahci/` would have links to individual controllers and they contain links to `ataX`...

Answer (score 0):

I too was running into this situation where the source `/dev/sdx` device would disappear shortly after `ddrescue`'s startup and knew that unplugging and re-plugging in the USB "toaster" I was using to attach the SATA drive to the system would cause it to be re-found.

Restarting ddrescue would allow it to run for a few minutes, before crashing shortly thereafter.  Using `lsblk`, it was easy to see if the drive was connected, or not.  Anyway, I ran ddrescue several times on 1 Ubuntu system, then on a more up to date 19.04 Ubuntu, with a slightly older ddrescue (1.23).

Still experiencing the problem, even after trying the bind/unbind remedies mentioned above and elsewhere, I thought I'd simply try to run ddrescue on a CentOS 7 system (CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)), using ddrescue version 1.24 with `kernel 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 4 23:02:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and Success!

I've had numerous errors on the drive while running (as per /var/log/messages), but it's been running over 10 hours at this point without a single instance of the harddrive disappearing.

What made me try a CentOS system again was I ran into a similar recovery situation a couple of years ago and found that the CentOS 6 system I was using back then didn't lose the drive.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used a USB2NVME adaptor to get my failed drive re-initiated in seconds by just unplugging the USB adaptor and plugging back in.

This said, I found that direct cooling (using a 12V fan) of the NVME drive ensured that the drive no longer disappears. From the moment I cooled the drive, `ddrescue` no longer showed `ddrescue: Input file disappeared: No such file or directory`.